# What are my options to enable proper indentation and color coding in SunEditor's code-view on NextJS?

Tags: next.js, frontend, rich-text-editor, suneditor

I am using SunEditor in my NextJS application.
"next": "^10.0.4",
"suneditor": "^2.43.14",
"suneditor-react": "^3.5.0",
The codeview in sun-editor looks very bad, there is no proper indentation, no color optons for different tags, or auto-completion.
currently it looks like this =>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqTMb.png)

Is there a way to have this features in code-view of sun-editor??

In the documentation of sun-editor they had mentioned pluging in code-mirror. I tried adding code-miror but it is not working. With nextjs it throws a lot of error.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, have been stuck on this.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.